# Installing application to a remote system with eclipse: Failed to connect SFTP subsystem

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, sftp

I am working on a C Project with eclipse, the App has to run over an embbeded Linux remote system device. I 'm using the  Eclipse C/C++ Remote Launch plugin and I can launch the ssh Shell from eclipse, but when I try to install the binary through "run configurations" I get the error:

```
Error during file upload.
Failed to connect SFTP subsystem: Remote host may not have sftp-server installed :     java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
```

Comment: Check network connection with embedded device. Try to ping it. If device has static IP, ensure that host Ethernet adapter has compatible IP.

Comment: The connection is ok, I can launch the Shell and navigate through the device, the problema is when transfering the binnary and then I get this error

Comment: Try to make an SFTP connection from the command line.  See if the ssh daemons on the device are configured for SFTP.  You can also see if you have better luck with SCP.

Comment: The device is not configured for SFTP..  Can I configure eclipse for do it with SCP?

Comment: Sure, eclipse is extensively customizable, it's fairly easy to insert shell commands at most process stages. Presumably you can reconfigure this "remote launch plugin" or if not simply replace it with custom commands.